Compiling OCaml .cmm file
I wrote simple OCaml code like:
let rec fib(n: int) = 
  match n with
  | 0 -> 0
  | 1 -> 1
  | _ -> fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

With -dcmm option to ocamlopt, I could generate .cmm files following:

cmm:
(data)
(data int 3063 "camlTest__1": addr "camlTest__fib_267" int 72057594037927941)
(data int 1792 global "camlTest" "camlTest": int 1)
(data
 global "camlTest__gc_roots"
 "camlTest__gc_roots":
 addr "camlTest"
 int 0)
(function{test.ml:1,11-88} camlTest__fib_267 (n/268: val)
 (if (!= n/268 1)
   (if (!= n/268 3)
     (+
       (+ (app{test.ml:5,9-17} "camlTest__fib_267" (+ n/268 -2) val)
         (app{test.ml:5,20-28} "camlTest__fib_267" (+ n/268 -4) val))
       -1)
     3)
   1))

(function camlTest__entry ()
 (let clos/271 "camlTest__1" (store val(root-init) "camlTest" clos/271)) 1)

(data)

ocamlopt can compile OCaml code (.ml) into machine code, then can I generate machine code directly from .cmm files?
I didn't find any option that compile .cmm files to machine code in ocamlopt, so I tried to use Asmgen in ocaml-base-compiler modules.
However, Asmgen function requires Cmm.phrase type but did not found how to convert .cmm files to Cmm.phrase type.

Exactly how did you call ocamlopt to generate the file content shown?

I called ocamlopt -dcmm test.ml > test.cmm to generate the .cmm file

OCaml compiler flags starting with -d... are debugging flags mostly aimed at compiler developers. The -dcmm flag is no exception, and its output cannot be read back by the compiler (and is probably incomplete).
